# linux - routing between bridge networks without overlay

Tags: linux, linux-networking, ip-routing

Here's the scenario. There are two hosts in a subnet (both are virtualbox VMs) and both are on the same network 192.168.1.0.
I've additionally created two bridge interfaces with separate network slices.

**Question:**
Is there a way for the ip on host1 bridge to communicate with an ip on host2 bridge?
I'm looking for a way to configure the routes using `ip route` or similar, to route the L3 packets on one bridge to another without the need to install an additional networking layer like vxlan or something.

Configuration:

**Host1 interfaces:**

````
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:ca:4a:14 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.197/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global enp0s3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:feca:4a14/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever```

7: br-faf88cbd32f0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:28:8c:40:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.11.11.1/24 brd 172.11.11.255 scope global br-faf88cbd32f0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
````

**Host1 routing:**

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp0s3 proto static
172.11.11.0/24 dev br-faf88cbd32f0 proto kernel scope link src 172.11.11.1
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp0s3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.197
```

**Host2 interfaces:**

```
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:40:ae:5f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.196/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global enp0s3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe40:ae5f/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

92: br-037dfd7b32bc: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:fe:0d:54:86 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.11.12.1/24 brd 172.11.12.255 scope global br-037dfd7b32bc
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:feff:fe0d:5486/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**Host2 routing:**

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp0s3 proto static
172.11.12.0/24 dev br-037dfd7b32bc proto kernel scope link src 172.11.12.1
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp0s3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.196
```

Answer (score 3):

if I understand correctly, you want something connected to host1 or host2 through its bridge to talk to the other host ?

you would do

```
ip route add 172.11.11.0/24 via 192.168.1.197 # on host2
ip route add 172.11.12.0/24 via 192.168.1.196 # host1
```

but beware of firewall or NATs that could have been enabled by Virtualbox, they may break your routing

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Kernel IP Forwarding turned on?
You can check with:

```
 cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

If it returns a 1, it is enabled. If 0, it must be enabled on each host that you want to route traffic.
You can run this to enable it for your current shell:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

To make the change permament, you can edit /etc/sysctl.conf to add this on a new line:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

Once the sysctl.conf is updated, reboot or run this to load the new value from the file:

```
sysctl -p
```

It looks like you know the routing part.